# using htaccess to skip to a subfolder, invisibly to user

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

*(My apologies. There are a plethora of .htaccess questions on SO and the more I read the more confused I've become.)*

Currently I own:

- www.mydomain.com
- www.mydomain.org
- www.mydomain.net

though only the first gets any real traffic. All are pointed to my `/public_html/` folder.

I'd like to begin testing a site redesign, which is (and forever will be) located in `/public_html/SUB/`.

I'd like `www.mydomain.org` to point to `/public_html/SUB/` while I work on the redesign, and then once I'm done I'd like to add the `.com` and `.net` domains as well.

The sticky point is, I don't want visitors to see the `/SUB/` folder in their URL. I want that to be effectively masked forever after.

So, before my redesign is complete:

- www.mydomain.com goes to the old site at `/public_html/`
- www.mydomain.org goes to the new site at `/public_html/SUB/` but you can't see it in the URL

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once tests are done. Just change document root of you VirtualHost to

```
/public_html/SUB/
```

Or if you don't have access to httpd.conf or can't change document root because of some reason. Try following in your root `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ SUB/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sure, very clear, but how? Is that a standard cPanel feature? is that done via .htaccess?

Comment: Are you using shared hosting ?? You don't have access to httpd.conf?.

Comment: I made some changes to the answer to suit your need. Just try that and lemme know.